# Convert uint64 time for number of 100 nanosecond intervals since jan 1st 1601 to date time string

Tags: c++, datetime

I have a time value that starts off stored in a uint64.  The value is the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since jan 1st 1601.  I understand that Windows FILETIME type uses this format.  I need to get this uint64 converted to some object where I can read the year, date, hour, min, etc in string format so I can build a custom date time string.

How can I get that uint64 converted to something useful.  I get a compile error with all the ways I've tried to cast uint64 to file time, for example

```
uint64 big_int;  // this will end up containing the nanosecond interval time
.
.
.

FILETIME t = static_cast<FILETIME>(big_int);
```

Comment: Just convert it directly to a usable format: FileTimeToSystemTime((FILETIME*)&big_int, &systime); where systime is a variable of type SYSTEMTIME.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've taken it as a challenge to perform this computation using [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html), [`<chrono>` Utilities](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html), and the C++11 `<chrono>` facilities.

From [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) we need:

```
template <class Int>
constexpr
Int
days_from_civil(Int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept;
```

which converts a y/m/d triple into a number of days before/since 1970-01-01, and:

```
template <class Int>
constexpr
std::tuple<Int, unsigned, unsigned>
civil_from_days(Int z) noexcept;
```

which converts a number of days before/since 1970-01-01 to a y/m/d triple.

From [`<chrono>` Utilities](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html) we need:

```
template <class To, class Rep, class Period>
To
floor(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d);
```

which is very similar to `std::chrono::duration_cast`, except that it rounds towards negative infinity, instead of towards zero (makes a difference for rounding negative values).

First we need a datetime object to hold all of the info we want:

```
struct datetime
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    int nanoseconds;
};
```

And a printing facility is convenient for demonstration purposes (which should be customized to whatever format is desired):

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const datetime& dt)
{
    char fill = os.fill();
    os.fill('0');
    os << dt.year << '-';
    os << std::setw(2) << dt.month << '-';
    os << std::setw(2) << dt.day << " T ";
    os << std::setw(2) << dt.hour << ':';
    os << std::setw(2) << dt.minute << ':';
    os << std::setw(2) << dt.second << '.';
    os << std::setw(9) << dt.nanoseconds;
    os.fill(fill);
    return os;
}
```

I've chosen units of `nanoseconds` as the precision of `datetime`, which is slightly overkill.  You can easily set this to whatever is desired.

Next it is convenient to declare two custom `std::chrono::duration`'s:

One to represent days (exactly 24 hours):

```
typedef std::chrono::duration
        <
            int,
            std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>
        > days;
```

And one to represent the 100 nanosecond interval from the problem statement:

```
typedef std::chrono::duration
        <
            std::int64_t, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<100>, std::nano>
        > wtick;
```

Now we have all the tools necessary to convert a `std::uint64_t` to a `datetime`, (the subject of this question):

```
datetime
datetime_from_wtick(wtick t)
{
    // Get the number of days between 1601-01-01 and 1970-01-01
    constexpr days epoch{days_from_civil(1601, 1, 1)};
    // eppoch is a negative number of days, so add it to get time since 1970-01-01
    wtick utc_time = t + epoch;
    days d = floor<days>(utc_time);  // Get #days before/since 1970-01-01
    datetime r;
    // Split #days into year/month/day
    std::tie(r.year, r.month, r.day) = civil_from_days(d.count());
    utc_time -= d;  // Subtract off #days to leave hours:minutes:seconds.fractional
    auto h = floor<std::chrono::hours>(utc_time);  // Get hours
    r.hour = h.count();
    utc_time -= h;  // Subtract off hours to leave minutes:seconds.fractional
    auto m = floor<std::chrono::minutes>(utc_time);  // Get minutes
    r.minute = m.count();
    utc_time -= m;  // Subtract off minutes to leave seconds.fractional
    auto s = floor<std::chrono::seconds>(utc_time);  // Get seconds
    r.second = s.count();
    utc_time -= s;  // Subtract off seconds to leave fractional seconds
    std::chrono::nanoseconds ns = utc_time;  // Get nanoseconds
    r.nanoseconds = ns.count();
    return r;
}
```

This solution works by simply shifting the epoch to 1970-01-01, then truncating off the number of days, then the number of hours, then the number of minutes, etc., until we get down to fractions of a second.  The number of days is further split into a triple: y/m/d.

The only reason to shift the epoch is to take advantage of the fully-debugged, high-performance, and extremely-robust formulas in [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html).

This solution ignores the existence of [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds).  My guess is that Windows FILETIME does too.  However if it does not, you can take [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds) into account by building a table that maps `datetime` to #seconds to add.  For example if the `datetime` extends beyond the current  [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds) table, you add 25 seconds to get the "true" difference between now and 1601-01-01.  My experience is that computers are using [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which just glosses over [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds).

Testing it all out with:

```
int
main()
{
    std::cout << datetime_from_wtick(wtick(130330211760000005)) << '\n';
}
```

Which should give:

```
2014-01-01 T 03:39:36.000000500
```

Which is intended to represent a `datetime` in the UTC timezone.

There are two primary points to this post:

1. Used correctly, `<chrono>` can be used to virtually eliminate all conversion constants.  This example introduces just a few conversion constants which are used to define custom `std::chrono:duration`s, and an epoch shift.  After that, the machinery just works, eliminating common errors.
2. [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) has some really useful and efficient algorithms.

**Update**

Working with unsigned durations is really error prone, and 63 bits of `wtick`s is plenty of range.  Changed `wtick::rep` to `int64_t`.  This gives much better results:

```
int
main()
{
    std::cout << datetime_from_wtick(wtick(0)) << '\n';
    std::cout << datetime_from_wtick(wtick(864000000000)) << '\n';
    std::cout << datetime_from_wtick(wtick(130330211760000005)) << '\n';
    std::cout << datetime_from_wtick(wtick(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)) << '\n';
}

1601-01-01 T 00:00:00.000000000
1601-01-02 T 00:00:00.000000000
2014-01-01 T 03:39:36.000000500
30828-09-14 T 02:48:05.477580700
```

### C++20 Update

Over the years, since this answer was first posted, the [`chrono`-Compatible Low-Level Date Algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) evolved into a [free, open-source date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), which further evolved into a C++ standards proposal and was accepted into the `<chrono>` library for C++20 (your vendor may or may not yet implement it).

The result is that `datetime_from_wtick` can be implemented much more easily now:

```
std::string
datetime_from_wtick(wtick wt)
{
    auto constexpr epoch_diff =
      std::chrono::sys_days{} - std::chrono::sys_days{std::chrono::January/1/1601};
    return std::format("{:%F T %T}", std::chrono::sys_time{wt - epoch_diff});
}
```

This simple little function gives the exact same output as shown previously.  But it is much easier to read and understand.