# C++: Converting 100-nanosecond intervals since jan 1st 1601 into current date and time

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, c++-chrono

I have a timestamp value that is the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since Jan 1st 1601. I would like to convert this into current date and time preferably DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS. How to do this in modern c++ with chrono library.

Note: Referred this answer from SO but seems like not straight forward
[Convert uint64 time for number of 100 nanosecond intervals since jan 1st 1601 to date time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384402/convert-uint64-time-for-number-of-100-nanosecond-intervals-since-jan-1st-1601-to)

In excel the below formula worked

```
=8.64*10^11*(<timestampin100ns>+109205)
```

Can the same be used in C++? If so how to covert to date and time.

Comment: Is your excel formula correct? Looks like parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: Duplicate updated to take into account changes in C++ over the last 8 years.